# HBase cassandra couchdb mongodb..any fundamental difference?

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, hbase, couchdb, nosql

I just wanted to know if there is a fundamental difference between hbase, cassandra, couchdb and monogodb ? In other words, are they all competing in the exact same market and trying to solve the exact same problems. Or they fit best in different scenarios?

All this comes to the question, what should I chose when. Matter of taste?

Thanks,

Federico

Comment: This up to date article is helpful: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are some long answers from **@Bohzo**. (but they are good links)

The truth is, they're "kind of" competing. But they definitely have different strengths and weaknesses and they definitely don't all solve the same problems.

For example Couch and Mongo both provide Map-Reduce engines as part of the main package. HBase is (basically) a layer over top of Hadoop, so you also get M-R via Hadoop. Cassandra is highly focused on being a Key-Value store and has plug-ins to "layer" Hadoop over top (so you can map-reduce).

Some of the DBs provide MVCC (Multi-version concurrency control). Mongo does not.

All of these DBs are intended to scale horizontally, but they do it in different ways. All of these DBs are also trying to provide flexibility in different ways. Flexible document sizes or REST APIs or high redundancy or ease of use, they're all making different trade-offs.

So to your question: *In other words, are they all competing in the exact same market and trying to solve the exact same problems?*

1. **Yes**: they're all trying to solve the issue of database-scalability and performance.
2. **No**: they're definitely making different sets of trade-offs.

What should you start with?

Man, that's a tough question. I work for a large company pushing tons of data and we've been through a few years. We tried Cassandra at one point a couple of years ago and it couldn't handle the load. We're using Hadoop everywhere, but it definitely has a steep learning curve and it hasn't worked out in some of our environments. More recently we've tried to do Cassandra + Hadoop, but it turned out to be a lot of configuration work.

Personally, my department is moving several things to **MongoDB**. Our reasons for this are honestly just simplicity.

Setting up Mongo on a linux box takes minutes and doesn't require root access or a change to the file system or anything fancy. There are no crazy config files or java recompiles required. So from that perspective, Mongo has been the easiest "gateway drug" for getting people on to KV/Document stores.

Comment: Which part? I know some people using Membase (memcache w/ persistence). It's easy to manage and has a nice UI for doing so. But it's also not trying to do very much. CouchDB has sold itself as being very good for setup with multi-master, but I've never had to use this at all. CouchDB has secondary indexes and several similar features to MongoDB, so it's really about how comfortable you are using it all.

Comment: IS mongo better then Cassandra for writes? Cassandra writes happens in memory and everyone says cassandra just works very well with writes. Is mongo even better ?

Comment: This answer is over 2 years old and these products have all evolved since this. Cassandra in particular has come a long way. At this point, I don't think they're comparable at all. As in, _MongoDB is not better *or* worse than Cassandra for writes_. Why? MongoDB is *CP*, dedicated to ensuring that writes are consistent. Cassandra is *AP*, dedicated to ensuring that writes are available. This means that they are not trying to provide the same things, so how are they really comparable?

Answer (score 5):

- CouchDB and MongoDB are document stores
- Cassandra and HBase are key-value based

[Here is a detailed comparison between HBase and Cassandra](https://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/24/hbase-vs-cassandra-why-we-moved/)
[Here is a (biased) comparison between MongoDB and CouchDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Comparing+Mongo+DB+and+Couch+DB)

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: test before you use in production.

I can offer my experience with both **HBase** (extensive) and **MongoDB** (just starting).

Even though they are not the same kind of stores, they solve the same problems:

- scalable storage of data
- random access to the data
- low latency access

We were very enthusiastic about HBase at first. It is built on Hadoop (which is rock-solid), it is under Apache, it is active... what more could you want? Our experience:

- HBase is fragile
- administrator's nightmare (full of configuration settings where default ones are less than perfect, nontransparent configuration, changes from version to version,...)
- loses data (unless you have set the X configuration and changed Y to... you get the point :) - we found that out when HBase crashed and we lost 2 hours (!!!) of data because WAL was not setup properly
- lacks secondary indexes
- lacks any way to perform a backup of database without shutting it down

All in all, HBase was a nightmare. Wouldn't recommend it to anyone except to our direct competitors. :)

MongoDB solves all these problems and many more. It is a delight to setup, it makes administrating it a simple and transparent job and the default configuration settings actually make sense. You can perform (hot) backups, you can have secondary indexes. From what I read, I wouldn't recommend MapReduce on MongoDB (JavaScript, 1 thread per node only), but you can use Hadoop for that.

And it is also VERY active when compared to HBase.

Also:
[http://www.google.com/trends?q=HBase%2CMongoDB](http://www.google.com/trends?q=HBase,MongoDB)

Need I say more? :)

**UPDATE:** many months later I must say MongoDB delivered on all accounts and more. The only real downside is that hosting companies do not offer it the way they offer MySQL. ;) 
It also looks like MapReduce is bound to become [multi-threaded](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4258) in 2.2. Still, I wouldn't use MR this way. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is good for writing the data. it has advantage of "writes never fail". It has no single point failure.

HBase is very good for data processing. HBase is based on Hadoop File System (HDFS) so HBase dosen't need to worry for data replication, data consistency. HBase has the single point of failure. I am not really sure that what does it's mean if it has single point of failure then it is somhow similar to RDBMS where we have single point of failure. I might be wrong in sense since I am quite new.

How abou RIAK ? Does someone has experience using RIAK. I red some where that you need to pay, I am not sure. Need explanation.

One more thing which one you will prefer to use when you are only concern to reading a lot of data. You don't have any concern with writing. Just imagine you have database with pitabyte and you want to make fast search which NOSQL database would you prefer ?